# LoadError in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having issues requiring `'digest/sha1'`.

```
~$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr --program-suffix=19 --enable-shared
~$ make
~$ make install
~$ irb19
irb(main):001:0> require 'digest/sha1'
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/matan/usr/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_SHA1_Finish
  Referenced from: /Users/matan/usr/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 - /Users/matan/usr/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/i386-darwin9.8.0/digest/sha1.bundle
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/matan/usr/bin/irb19:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

I know some standard modules require fine, while others don't. If i'd say `require 'yaml'` or even `require 'digest'` then that works fine. I am using OS X 10.5.8, with Ruby 1.9.1-p378. The system-wide install of Ruby 1.8.6 works fine.

Just last week I uninstalled Ruby and re-installed it. When I first installed Ruby I installed it in a similar manner, from source prefixed at my local `$HOME/usr` directory. I tried removing each and every file `make install` installs, then re-installing, but that didn't help.

Do you have an idea what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably related to OpenSSL (Ruby uses OpenSSL for MD5/SHA1, at least if available). You could fix this by compiling a newer version of OpenSSL and linking against it on your own (`./configure ... --with-openssl-dir=path/to/openssl`).

Unfortunately you cannot install openssl via homebrew. However, apparently, if you are using macports, there is a port available: `sudo port install openssl`.

But what I would recommend is to simply use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com):

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
rvm package install openssl
rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

You can then switch between 1.8 and 1.9:

```
rvm use system
ruby --version # => 1.8
rvm use 1.9.1
ruby --version # => 1.9.1
```

I did the compiling on my own for a long time, even wrote my own little script managing updating. But RVM ist just so much better at handling this. If you are going to try RVM, just swing by the #rvm channel at freenode, people are always willing to help there.

As an aside, 1.9.1 has a lot of rough edges and I would rather recommend switching to the 1.9.2 branch (or at least switch to 1.9.2p0 as soon as released).

Konstantin

Comment: Indeed, with RVM's Ruby 1.9.2-head I have no issue requiring digest/sha1. But I still wonder what goes wrong when I install from source. I'm also having issues installing any Ruby other than 1.9.2-head, but I suppose this belongs in a new, distinct question.

Comment: I saw such an issue being fixed on a embedded Linux system by removing OpenSSL completely. But that actually breaks rubygems.

Comment: I think it should be `rvm pkg install openssl` not `rvm package install openssl`