# LoadError: dlopen(digest/sha1.bundle): Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_SHA1_Finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, rbenv

**Ruby stopped working on my brother's machine recently.**

- `gem` commands
- `rails server`
- `rails console`

All failed with the following error:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'digest/sha1'

LoadError: dlopen(~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_SHA1_Finish
  Referenced from: ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

 in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle - ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/sha1.bundle
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

*He tried different versions of Ruby. Reinstalling everything with `rvm`. Running `rvm implode` and reinstalling `rvm`. Switching to `rbenv`. Several Rubies installed via `ruby-build`. `brew install ruby`.*

*All had the same problem.*

*If he uninstalled all rubies, the OS supplied version in `/usr/bin/ruby` worked. But it's 1.8.7.*

*After hours of troubleshooting, we arrived at the solution below. I hope it helps you avoid some pain.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Possible solutions:**

1. **`$ unset C_INCLUDE_PATH`** and reinstall Ruby

   *This is the solution that worked for me.*

   `$ echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH`

   If `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is set, it will break Ruby builds. Remove it from your environment; either temporarily with `$ unset C_INCLUDE_PATH`, or permanently (might be in .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile); then reinstall ruby.
2. It might be related to OpenSSL, RVM, XCode's Command Line Tools (gcc), or other build issues.

   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032601/loaderror-in-ruby) if the previous solution didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone, like me, coming here because of an error like this:

```
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/sebkomianos/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
Referenced from: /Users/sebkomianos/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.0.0/openssl.bundle
Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

One solution ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492787/ruby-bundle-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method-loaderror/25493698#25493698)) might be to reinstall your version of ruby. eg: `rbenv install 2.0.0-p247`

Comment: Reinstalling ruby worked for me. The `unset C_INCLUDE_PATH` wasn't necessary.